# Limit of 1010 reached when loadtesting Apache/PHP with Tsung

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tsung

I've been testing an Ubuntu server A running Apache/PHP using Tsung from a server B and I reached something that looks like a limit, but I can't find any idea on what it might be : here is a graph showing the behavior => https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mspqp.png The value given as max by Tsung is 1010 which doesn't look like anything I know from Apache/PHP/MySQL/Ubuntu configuration.

Server A was a virtual machine at DigitalOcean, running a simple installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache2/PHP5/APC (Perfork MaxClients 384, ServerLimit 500) : usage of CPU or RAM was OK, not full. Apache's server-status page also showed open slots so the limit doesn't seem to come from there.

Server B was another virtual machine at DigitalOcean running a simple installationg of Ubuntu 12.04 and Tsung.

Webapp code included some PHP and some MySQL requests (500 max connections).

I can't find any configuration value in Apache/PHP/Ubuntu that would explain a 1000 or 1010 limit, any ideas on where to look ?

Answer (score 1):

Please update below parameters which would support up to 8000 simultaneous connections.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   ServerLimit             250
   StartServers             10
   MinSpareThreads          75
   MaxSpareThreads         250 
   ThreadLimit              64
   ThreadsPerChild          32
   MaxClients             8000
   MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```